# Передать через Bundle текущее нажатие по LISTView

Tags: java, android

Логика работы. По нажатию на кнопку перехожу из MainActiviy => Fragment(меняет динамически ListView with Data) =>(при нажатие на подстроку перехожу в FragmentDialog(для редактирования))
Получается в Диалог хочу пережать данные уже которые есть, в ListView , но возвращает первый пункт,а я нажал к примеру на второй,третий,чтобы ередать текущий, использываю view.findViewById не принимает,как передать текущий?

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener (new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener () {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

            bundle.putInt (fragment_dialog_coast.DIALOG_ID,R.id.id);
            bundle.putInt (fragment_dialog_coast.DIALOG_COASTS,R.id.tvName);
            bundle.putInt (fragment_dialog_coast.DIALOG_SUMMA,R.id.tvSumma);
            bundle.putInt (fragment_dialog_coast.DIALOG_DESCRIPTION,R.id.description);

            fragment_dialog_coast.setArguments (bundle);
            curItem = id;
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

напишите во фрагменте:

```
 public static MyFragment newInstance(int number) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(NUMBER, number);
        ...
        MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment ();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
```

вызывайте где нужно: `MyFragment.newInstance(number)`

можете передавать неограниченное количество аргументов, записывая их в `Bundle` в `newInstance`

Если же у вас уже есть рабочий фрагмент, просто пропишите в нем функции `setNumber` (и т.д.) и вызывайте его через экземпляр `myFragment.setNumber(number);`

Если вы работаете с `View` фрагмента, во втором случае может быть `NullPointerExeption`, если вы вызовете функцию до его добавления.